# relying on timestamp rather than sequence in Oracle RAC

Tags: oracle, timestamp

[Oracle RAC and sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866959/oracle-rac-and-sequences)

I have read this answer. I have one more question.

*When one node asks for timestamp( say in GMT, and the nodes are in different timezones), does this node need to ask node-master for timestamp everytime it needs to save?*
I am wondering if it does ask the master-node, then there is no advantage of using sequence vs timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, about your intentions, but sequence is granted to be unique. Not ordered, but unique.

That is the main advantage (I would rather say purpose) of sequence over timestamp.

Comment: jakup.petr this should be a comment on the question, not an answer.

Comment: Reference: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:312354500346307669

 both timestamps and sequences are monotonically increasing values. They are both going to be unique in your case (primary key) which means they hash pretty much perfectly.

Comment: You can go as high as 6 digits of precision. I think if the system needs more than 6 digits of precision after seconds, you are right. But, my question was when we say current_timestamp, how does Oracle node get the timestamp?