# oracle mlog sequence$$ ordering

Tags: oracle, sequence

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513936/oracle-sequence-value-are-not-ordered) question, the sequence$$ in a mlog table may not be guaranteed depending on CACHE and ORDER & NOCACHE and ORDER. I don't know how my database is setup, and I doubt I have access to find out.

Could there be a chance for data to be out of sequence by a very large amount. The dmltype$$ of I has a sequence number = 21759899 while dmltype$$ of U = 5659, 653075, and 653077.

If it makes a difference, there is not a large amount of activity for this database.