# Oracle Sequence does not increase after nextval

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

Calling Oracle sequence nextval seems irregular. Our business constraint(unique token) is to generate unique number, so we use oracle sequence. We use hibernate spring boot application. But, in this case, we calling nextval by native query (JDBC), so that hibernate management does not take place. But, after some time running the application in production, out unique token get unique constraint exception, as oracle sequence tries to generate same sequence number or it does not increase sequence value after some time. 
In all our unique token, sequence value difference is like 1 or 2. But when sequence value do not increase (upon nextval), manual sequence increment by 2494 (cache 1000 ORDER).  Our sequence value is ORDER but stuck in some values, need to increment by 2494 to maintain our uniqueness

Our sequence definition is like this:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_98090 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 1000 ORDER NOCYLE NOPARTITION;
```

To solve this, manually we increase sequence value, so that our unique business constraint (unique token) do not get any unique constraint exception.

Our application runs on multiple servers.

We debug the sequence value from outside, we see that oracle sequence value do not increase.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_98090 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 1000 ORDER NOCYLE NOPARTITION;
```

```java
String queryString = "SELECT " + dbSequence + ".NEXTVAL FROM DUAL";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString);
BigDecimal issuedTokenBin = null;
try {
    issuedTokenBin = (BigDecimal) query.getSingleResult();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Error :", ex);
}
```

As we get the sequence from oracle sequence, it should always return incremented value.

[image: From TID value 3009053444 to next TID 3009091522, last part of unique token i.e. oracle sequence stuck. Unless we manually increase it]

From the image:  Oracle sequence got stuck at first selected row (app got unique constraint violation). Then we manually increase it and application got going. last 8 digits of the unique token i.e. 79140 and 81634 comes from oracle sequence.

Comment: Your Sequence definition is not working for me. [demo of error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d6a79f4d03b1a1a621fdbfb7816e4798) .. Can you please edit and correct it?

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 `nopartition` is an [undocumented feature of 12.1](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9523071800346490539) that leaked out, but was removed in 12.2

Comment: It's **highly unlikely** you're calling `seq.nextval` and the database **isn't** incrementing it. Are you sure you're passing the same name for `dbSequence` when you get this error?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon I tried removing `nopartition` in demo of error and also tried it in 11g. Still facing the same issue. `CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_98090 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 1000 ORDER NOCYLE` is not working.

Comment: We are using Oracle 11. I just create a sequence from the query: CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TEST INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 1000 ORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION;

Comment: Run the query in sqlplus.

Comment: @ChrisSaxon: Yes we are calling the same dbSequence variable, because we increase sequence value manually from the outside, application works.

Comment: Hibernate has a strong support for *caching*, do you not *by accident* use this feature to get the `nextval`; this would be fatal...

Comment: *"We debug the sequence value from outside, we see that oracle sequence value do not increase."* How exactly did you do that? It's actually pretty hard - or at least not obvious - to see that info.

Comment: @APC We see that the unique value we are expecting and the sequence value which should be same as sequence provide, are not same. Oracle sequence value is much lesser than we expect (2494 to be exact).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber How can we know that we are using hibernate? We are using pure plain JDBC query.

Comment: But **how** did you see this lower value? What query did you run?

Comment: @APC: in sqlplus (in production)

Comment: @APC our sequence value is ORDER but stuck in some values, need to increment by 2494 to maintain our uniqueness.

Comment: Update the question to include the **exact** steps you take to reproduce this issue. Every query you run, every call you make.

Comment: "*need to increment by 2494 to maintain our uniqueness*" - strongly indicates that you are doing INSERTs somewhere **without** calling `nextval`. Probably outside of your JDBC code - maybe it's Hibernate that uses cached values that your JDBC code also used.

Comment: @ChrisSaxon: We cannot reproduce the problem so far.

Comment: So how are you spotting the issue? Show us _everything_ you do; not just the snippet generating the sequence values

Comment: @ChrisSaxon: could you please see the attached image? Oracle sequence got stucked at first selected row (app got unique constraint violation). Then we manually increase it and application got going.  last 8 digits of the unique token i.e. 79140 and 81634 comes from oracle sequence.

Comment: In the image, you are doing a substring of a numerical value. Why is that necessary and what comes after the "last digit" if you don't? I'm thinking perhaps the sequence values have gotten so high that the (BigDecimal) conversion is rounding the last digit, causing a duplicate.

Comment: From what you've said it doesn't sound like a problem with the sequence; it sounds like someone or some process inserted around 2500 rows of data without using the sequence, maybe using a max+1 pattern. You had to adjust the sequence to account for those manual values?

Comment: I agree with @AlexPoole - the behaviour you describe is highly unlikely to occur from using a sequence properly and highly likely to occur from an insert statement not using the sequence at all.

Comment: @APC and Alex Pole, we will be checking..

Answer (score -2):

The overall benefit of sequence caching is speed: the higher the caching value, the fewer times that Oracle must go to the database and obtain a cache of sequences. The negative effect of caching is that once a cache of sequences exists, if there is a re-boot of the database, Oracle abandons any values that were in the cache.

Therefore, if you do not want to leave gaps in your sequence values, then you must pay the price by setting your sequence to NOCACHE.

Comment: The question is complaining about repeated values, not gaps? Also nocache doesn't necessarily mean gapless (rollback, for a start) and it doesn't usually lose values in a controlled restart.

Answer (score -3):

Do you really need caching in your sequence. How about using the following :

CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TEST INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE ORDER NOCYCLE ;

Regards
Akash

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as the problem (if one exists) isn't clear; but [this can also have a big performance penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515836/266304).

Comment: Thanks Alex. Really helpful info with regards to performance degradation because of NOCACHE.